# how can I move a div when hovering an other div in CSS?

Tags: css

I'd like my div to move when hovering an existing div

```css
.divToMove {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}

@keyframes slideIn {
    from {
        transform: translateY(-100%);
    }
    to {
        transform: translateY(-35%);
    }
}

.divToHover:hover .divToMove {
    animation: slideIn 0.5s forwards;
}
```

the div is "stuck" where it originally was placed, I'd like it to transition from -100% in Y to -35

Comment: `.divToHover:hover .divToMove` will select `.divToMove` that is inside the `.divToHover` element.

Comment: @rozsazoltan yes

Answer (score 3):

[Adjacent sibling combinator - `+` in CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) - MDN Docs

> The adjacent sibling combinator (+) separates two selectors and matches the second element only if it immediately follows the first element, and both are children of the same parent element.

```css
/* only need the container for testing purposes, to position the two divs next to each other in the center of the screen */
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.divToHover {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
}

.divToHover:hover {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.divToMove {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

/* when I hover over the .divToHover class, add the styles of the .divToMove class */
.divToHover:hover + .divToMove {
  transform: translateY(-35%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- Hover -->
  <div class="divToHover">
    Hover me!
  </div>
  <!-- Moved -->
  <div class="divToMove">
    Moving Div
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly modify other element's styling on hover. You need to make use of [CSS Combinators](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp)

Here, I have used General Sibling Selector (~), which selects all `.divToMove` elements that are next siblings of `.divToHover`.

If `.divToMove` and `.divToHover` remain adjacent, you can also use the `+` combinator.

```css
.divToMove {
    margin-top: 100px;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}

@keyframes slideIn {
    from {
        transform: translateY(-100%);
    }
    to {
        transform: translateY(-35%);
    }
}

.divToHover:hover ~ .divToMove {
    animation: slideIn 0.5s forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="divToHover">HOVER</div>
<div class="divToMove">MOVE</div>
```